# the matching pattern for TabClosed autocmd

Tags: autocmd

If I want to setup a `TabClosed` autocmd for a specific tab page only, what should I do?

Can I use the `autocmd {pat}` argument? Is this `{pat}` still matched against the filename?

Moreover, the `t:` variable is associated with the tab page that is going to be entered, not the tab page that is closed.

PS: I know that `<afile>` can be used as the tab page number, but tab page can be moved around after the `autocmd` is set. So a tab page nr may not work. Is there a concept as `tab page id` like the `winid`?