# alternative of `BufWinLeave` autocmd that triggers when buffer goes invisible from the screen

Tags: autocmd

The `BufWinLeave` event is not trigger when the buffer is still visible in another window, which includes the case **when it is shown in a window in another tab**. This is a annoying since only **visible in the current tab** is truly visible; and you cannot see a buffer in the screen when it is **only "displayed" in another tab**.

I want an autocmd to be executed when a buffer goes invisible from the **screen (current tab)**. What is the best approach to achieve this?

---

Let me make it more specific. I want an autocmd for this

1. a window's (W) buffer (B1) is changed to another one (B2) or that window is destroyed;
2. B1 is not displayed in other windows of the current tabpage

This is equivalent to say:

- B1 disappears from the current tabpage (i.e. the screen)

Note that if the whole current tabpage is closed, the entering tabpage becomes the current tabpage. So "disappears from the screen" is the more accurate statement.

I do not care about whether B1 is shown in other tabpages; and it should not be triggered when the cursor moves between splits of the current tabpage, like what `BufLeave` and `WinLeave` do.

Originally, I thought this might be described by `BufWinLeave`, but I realized today that `BufWinLeave` does not work like this. `BufWinLeave` is not triggered when the buffer is displayed in another tabpage.

Now, in my understanding, `BufWinLeave` works exactly the same as `BufHidden`:

- when a buffer turns to be not shown in any of the window in any tabpage.

Please tell me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: The TabLeave autocommand?

Comment: That is not I am looking for. The tab is not changed. I am doing simple change of buffer like `:b3` to switch out the current buffer.

Comment: Well, that is not clear from the description of the problem. Perhaps try the BufLeave autocommand then.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, thank you for your help. I updated the description. Please answer according to that if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you close the window of a buffer `B1` which is still displayed in another tabpage, `QuitPre`, `BufLeave` and `WinLeave` are fired in the context of `B1`. Then, `WinEnter` and `BufEnter` are fired in the context of the buffer where the focus goes (`B2`).
None of these events matches your description:

> B1 disappears from the current tabpage (i.e. the screen)

However, you could listen to `BufLeave` to:

- capture the number of the current buffer (`B1`) and the one of the current tabpage
- install a fire-once autocmd listening to `BufEnter` to, later, check whether `B1` is still displayed in the current tabpage

And when `B1` does become invisible, you could fire a custom `BufInvisible` event (using `:doautocmd`, see `:h :do`).

Finally, you could listen to this new event to execute an arbitrary command.

---

As an example:

```
augroup will_buffer_become_invisible
    au!
    au BufLeave * call s:will_buffer_become_invisible()
augroup END

fu! s:will_buffer_become_invisible() abort
    let s:bufnr = bufnr('%')
    let s:tabnr = tabpagenr()
    augroup has_buffer_become_invisible
        au!
        au TabClosed * exe 'au! has_buffer_become_invisible'
            \ | aug! has_buffer_become_invisible
        au BufEnter * call s:has_buffer_become_invisible()
            \ | exe 'au! has_buffer_become_invisible'
            \ | aug! has_buffer_become_invisible
    augroup END
endfu

fu! s:has_buffer_become_invisible() abort
    let other_winids = filter(win_findbuf(s:bufnr), {i,v -> get(get(getwininfo(v), 0, {}), 'tabnr', 0) == s:tabnr})
    if empty(other_winids) && exists('#User#BufInvisible')
        do <nomodeline> User BufInvisible
    endif
endfu
```

To listen to `BufInvisible`, you would write something like:

```
augroup test_BufInvisible
    au!
    au User BufInvisible echom 'a buffer has become invisible'
augroup END
```

---

> In `#User#BufInvisible`, is (1) `User` interpreted as group and `BufInvisible`
>   as event; or (2) `User` as event and `BufInvisible` as pattern?
>   (see the syntax for `exists()`).

Technically, `User` is an event. It's listed among other events at `:h User`, and the help refers to it as an event at `:h :do`:

> You probably want to use <nomodeline> for events that are not used when loading
>   a buffer, such as `|User|`.

It's a special kind of event, because it's never fired by Vim automatically. You have to fire it yourself by executing `:doautocmd`. It allows to create your own event.
As a result, `BufInvisible` is a pattern in:

- `exists('#User#BufInvisible')`
- `:do <nomodeline> User BufInvisible`
- `au User BufInvisible`

Although, if you look at `:h :do`, what follows the event is not a pattern, but a file name:

```
:do[autocmd] [<nomodeline>] [group] {event} [fname]
                                            ^^^^^^^
```

But here, `BufInvisible` is just a pattern, not a file name. It's matched against the name of the custom `User` event which has been fired.

---

> If `BufInvisible` is the not a pattern, can I add a pattern to the `au`? I do not know the syntax for `au User`.

`BufInvisible` is the pattern, so you can't add another one after `:au`.
The syntax for `:au User` is:

```
au User <your custom event> <your command>
```

As an example, if your custom event is `MyNewEvent`, and you want to log a message in `:messages` whenever it's fired, you could write:

```
au User MyNewEvent echom 'MyNewEvent has been fired'
```

---

> why do you use `exe 'au! has_buffer_become_invisible'` instead of `au! has_buffer_become_invisible`? Is it because au handles `|` by itself.

You're right, `:autocmd` considers the bar as being part of its argument, and can't be followed by another Vim command. It's explained at `:h :bar`.

The `:execute` prevents `:autocmd` from seeing what's outside the string, so it should leave `:aug!` alone. The purpose of the latter is to remove the augroup, once `:au!` has cleared it (you can't remove an augroup when it's not empty; see `:h :augroup-delete`).

Comment: Thanks. This seems feasible. I will have some test later. I have a few questions on the code: In `#User#BufInvisible#`, is (1) `User` interpreted as group and `BufInvisible` as event; or (2) `User` as event and `BufInvisible` as pattern? (see the syntax for `exists()`). If `BufInvisible` is the not a pattern, can I add a pattern to the au? I do not know the syntax for `au User`

Comment: why do you use `exe 'au! has_buffer_become_invisible'` instead of `au! has_buffer_become_invisible`? Is it because `au` handles `|` by itself?

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation.  Here I feel that the tabnr handling is not so correct. If the tabpage is closed completely, it will check the wrong tabpage. Is there a concept of tabpage id? I once asked another question about [TabClose](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/the-matching-pattern-for-tabclosed-autocmd), which you may be able to answer.

Comment: You're right, the code doesn't properly handle the case where a tabpage is closed. Between `BufLeave` and `BufEnter`, Vim should fire the `TabLeave`, `TabClosed` and `TabEnter` events. I'm not sure how you want Vim to behave in such a case. The way I understood your request, I assumed that your definition of the event was: the buffer disappears from the current tabpage. When you close the current tabpage, the latter changes, so I wouldn't check whether the buffer is displayed in the new tabpage, because it's not the same anymore, and I would just cancel the `BufInvisible` event.

Comment: That's my understanding which may differ from yours. Anyway, to cancel the event, I'm not sure it would work, but you could install an autocmd listening to `TabClosed`, and use it to clear the augroup before the autocmd listening to `BufEnter` has a chance to be processed. I edited the code accordingly. As for the concept of a tabpage id, unfortunately I don't think it exists. If it did, it would probably be present inside the list `keys(getwininfo()[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @user938271's answer, I slightly changed the code so that it is more concise:

```
augroup will_buffer_become_invisible
    au! BufLeave * call s:will_buffer_become_invisible()
augroup END

fu! s:will_buffer_become_invisible() abort
    augroup has_buffer_become_invisible
        exe printf('au! BufEnter * call s:has_buffer_become_invisible(%d)', bufnr('%'))
    augroup END
endfu

fu! s:has_buffer_become_invisible(bufnr)
    try
        let other_wins = filter(range(1, winnr('$')), {i,v->winbufnr(v) == a:bufnr})
        if empty(other_wins) && exists('#User#BufInvisible')
            do <nomodeline> User BufInvisible
        endif
    finally
        au! has_buffer_become_invisible
        aug! has_buffer_become_invisible
    endtry
endfu
```

Note: here if you close a tabpage it will check whether the entering tabpage will have the buffer shown.